# How to call an object within another object using the id assigned to the child object

Tags: javascript

I created an object where I store the various attributes of a hex grid. 
I defined the id in the format of `x coord + y coord + z coord`

```
hex.id =  cX + "x" + cY + "y" + cZ + "z"; //where cX, cY and cZ are some numbers
// adding the hex to our hexList with the id as identifier
hexList[hex.id] = hex;  //hex is a graphics object
```

However, now I am unable to retrieve the hexlist object. I am sure that this has something to do with the type os names that I put in the id.

when I created it, I thought I would simply call `hexList.<some coord id>` and be able to use it.

I have attached my console log help you understand the issue. How do I call and use the objects in my hexList parent object, using the id (5x3y19z for eg.)?

```
> hexList
{0x0y0z: Object, 1x-1y0z: Object, 2x-2y0z: Object, 3x-3y0z: Object, 4x-4y0z: Object, 5x-5y0z: Object, 6x-6y0z: Object, 7x-7y0z: Object, 8x-8y0z: Object, 9x-9y0z: Object, 840 more…}
> hexList.10x-12y22z
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
```

I am new to JS and am sure the way I am defining the HexList is not proper. but I dont know whats wrong there.

Thinking that maybe the issue is with the id being taken as a number, I changed it up a bit;

```
hex.id =  "hex" + cX + "x" + cY + "y" + cZ + "z"; //where cX, cY and cZ are some numbers
// adding the hex to our hexList with the id as identifier
hexList[hex.id] = hex;  //hex is a graphics object
```

This gave me the answer;

```
> hexList
{hex0x0y0z: Object, hex1x-1y0z: Object, hex2x-2y0z: Object, hex3x-3y0z: Object, hex4x-4y0z: Object, hex5x-5y0z: Object, hex6x-6y0z: Object, hex7x-7y0z: Object, hex8x-8y0z: Object, hex9x-9y0z: Object, 840 more…}
> hexList.hex-10x-10y20z
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
> hexList.hex10x10y20z
undefined
```

so clearly the problem is the `-` sign. but I thought since these were all part of the id string, there shouldnt be a problem.

i know I can simple use `"n"`/`"p"` suffix instead of `-`/`+` signs in my code and make it work, but I was wondering if I can simply change the part where I call the object?

Comment: Square brackets notation: `hexList['10x-12y22z']`?

Comment: hexList[hex.id] or hexList["10x-12y22z"] return anything ?

Comment: thanks everyone. the brackets notations work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hexList.10x-12y22z
//         ^ That's not a valid character in property names
```

There's your problem.

JavaScript is interpreting that as:

```
hexList.10x - 12y22z;
```

Which isn't valid JS, obviously.

Replace your dot notation with bracket access like this:

```
hexList['10x-12y22z']
```

Comment: Thank you. I totally forgot about the brackets notation. I feel like an idiot now. :D

Comment: @RishavSharan: You're welcome :-) I'm pretty sure everyone has those _"Oh derp -.-"_ moments :P